# Counting the number of invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we are given a linear transformation $L: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ with characteristic polynomial $t^4+1$. Find the number of invaiant subspaces.

The roots of this polynomial are all complex. In particular, this factors as the product of two irreducible quadratics, call them $p(x), q(x)$ so by the fundamental theorem for modules over PIDs, $\mathbb{R}^4=\mathbb{R}[x]/(p(x)) \oplus \mathbb{R}[x]/(q(x))=A \oplus B$.

Thus, so far I have 4 invariant subspaces, $\{0\}, \mathbb{R}^4, A, B$. There can't be any invariant subspaces of dimension 1 since the eigenvalues are complex. But, how can I show there are no other invariant subspaces of dimension 2 or 3?

Comment: not 5th roots of unity.

Comment: yes, I will fix that.

Comment: You have shown $\mathbb R^4= A\oplus B$, suppose there are other non-trivial $L$- invariant subspace $U$, take $c\in U$ and consider $c=a+b$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, $L(a)\in A$ and is linear independent to $a$, $L(b)\in B$ and is linear independent to $b$. So $L(U)=V$ is the whole space. This is contradictory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we suppose that it exist a subspace $R$ of  dimension 2 such that $R$ is invariant by $L$ so $A\cap R$ will be invariant by $L$ too and the dimension of $A\cap R$ is :

**Case 1: $\dim(A\cap R)=0 $** that mean $A\cap R=\{0\}$ so $\mathbb{R}^4=A\oplus R=A\oplus B$ and then $R=B$.

**Case 2: $\dim(A\cap R)=1 $** that impossible because $L$ haven't a invariant subspace of dimension one.

**Case 3: $\dim(A\cap R)=2 $** and it's mean that $A\cap R=A$ so $R=A$.

Finally the only invariant subspaces of dimension 2 are $A$ and $B$

Comment: Very elegant, thank you.

Comment: you are welcome